# Vimgrep not matching regular expression properly

Tags: vim

If I do this:

```
:vimgrep /do_action\([ ]?'init'/ **/*.php
```

I get

```
E54: Unmatched \(
```

But I know that there are files with matching text. Why?

I would also be very grateful if someone could help me create a key mapping for cmd+l so that this search is initiated with "init" replaced with the word under the cursor, which I understand from various sources is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on kev's answer, here is your mapping:

```
nnoremap <D-i> :vimgrep //do_action([ ]\?'<c-r>=expand('<cword>')<cr>'/ **/*.php<cr>
```

But I'd advise you to not use the Command key in a mapping: it works only in MacVim and it's a good habit to seek portability everywhere possible.

The `<leader>` key is perfect for such things.

```
nnoremap <leader>i :vimgrep //do_action([ ]\?'<c-r>=expand('<cword>')<cr>'/ **/*.php<cr>
```

See `:help c_ctrl-r_=` and `:help leader`.

***edit***

I went a little too fast on this one. Not only I've added unnecessary cruft to kev's reworking of your command (silly `//`) but I didn't notice that it could be simplified. This one is tested and working:

```
nnoremap <leader>i :vim do_action(\s*'<c-r>=expand('<cword>')<cr> **/*.php<cr>
```

Sorry for the mess.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much. But there is a problem still that I cannot figure out. The :vimgrep alone works, but when using the key mapping I get errors (I tried to fix it myself to no avail): "]?'init'" [New File]
Cannot open file "]?'init'"
E480: No match: do_action([

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape `(` to match it. But you need to escape `?` to match 0~1 previous item. Try:

```
:vimgrep /do_action([ ]\?'init'/ **/*.php
```